# Google sheets function if cell is blank add text to another cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a dropshipping spreadsheet that I'm working on and I have a cell in one column that contains a tracking number, and another cell that I put "Yes" or "No" for if it has been shipped.

| Tracking# | Shipped |
| --- | --- |
| 13213654 | Yes |
|  | No |

I want my sheet to check if there is a tracking number and then add yes or no to the adjacent cell in the `shipped` column.

Can anyone help me with a script? I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A=""; "No"; "Yes"))
```

Comment: You are a genius! Here I am trying to figure out how to write a function with a for loop and you figure out how to do it in one line.. **Bows Down**